# is a right solution to zoom all the page for smaller monitors?

Tags: html, css

I've maded a html markup, and my monitor is big enough, but in the small monitors its a mess, I've maked a media queriese in css and just user `zoom` property, is this a right solution?

```
media query for 900px {

 body {
    zoom: 0.8;
 }

}

media query for 600px {

  body {

    zoom: 0.6;
 }
}
```

I just didn't had an idea on how to solve this, so I tried this, but I don't know what can be the cons of this solution?

Answer (score 0):

Well that is a way to dodge the problem.  Most conventional websites would alter their content to fit the screen.  You have the right idea, as long it fits all screen sizes what you are doing is temporally fine but think about making your design responsive.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the best way to fit your content within the small screens. If you have the resources and time you should implement a *true* responsive solution that scales everything accordingly ...

Pay attention when using that way because you could make your content unreadable. Imagine a `12px` text being scaled out but 80% that will be very difficult to read.

Also `zoom` is not supported at all by Firefox so you might want to use `transform: scale(x)` instead.